# When using strtol and input 2 zeros (00), then it only output one zero back?

Tags: c

The code below simply asks for your age and outputs a simple printf. What Im trying to do is input 000 and have it return 000 and not just 0.  What do i do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_LEN 80
#define EXTRA_SPACES 2

 int main(void)
{
char line[LINE_LEN + EXTRA_SPACES];
char * end;
int input_num;

/* get user input */
printf("Please enter your age: ");
fgets(line, LINE_LEN+EXTRA_SPACES, stdin);
/* check for buffer overflow */
if(line[strlen(line)-1]!='\n')
{
    printf("Error: buffer overflow\n\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
/* remove newline */
line[strlen(line)-1]=0;

/* retrieve number */
input_num = strtol(line, &end, 0);
if(*end)
{
    printf("Error: data entered was not numeric.\n\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
printf("you are %d years old.\n\n", input_num);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: Google 'printf format specifier'

Comment: but i want it to be saved in a variable as 000. not just printed or hardcoded.

Comment: @lemonsforyou, then you need to store it as a string. Otherwise it's not possible. A zero is a only one zero, not three or four.

Comment: so theres no chance i can set my age to 000

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: When you enter a 10-year-old, Is input `010` or just `10`? Special case of 0?

Comment: It's not octal - according to `strtol()` params, OP is using 0-base system :)

Comment: @qrdl when base order `0`, Number that begins with 0 is understood as octal.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You're correct, I didn't know about such `strtol()` behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to do it like this:

```
printf("you are %03d years old.\n\n", input_num);
```

Comment: i dont want to just print it 000. i want it to be saved as 000 not 0.

Comment: @lemonsforyou You need to read about integer type a bit. There is no such number as 000

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be saved as 000, your have to store input_num as a string, by using *sprintf* instead:

```
char    *buffer;

if (!(buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen("you are XXX years old.\n\n"))))
    return (MALLOC_ERROR);
if (input_num < 1000) // Avoiding format string attack
{
    sprintf(buffer, "your are %03d years old.\n\n", input_num);
    puts(buffer);
}
```

But if you want to store it as an int, the result will be 0. By the way it's the expected behavior: 000000 = 000 = 0000.0000 = 0